# web api - list all data types on a class

Tags: linq, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to list all the data types on a class and after give the information to a client

i know that i have to use the GetType. So here is what i have at the moment

```
               var variables = typeof(MockClass).GetType()
                                    .Select(field => field.Name)  //error: 'Type' does not contain a definition for select
                                    .ToList();
```

I'm trying to enter inside the class, use a query to select all the variables name and try to get their data type.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    var type = typeof(MockClass);

    var nestedTypes = new List<Type>();
    var typeNames = new List<string>();
    var propertiesNames = new List<string>();

    foreach(var p in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var t = p.PropertyType;
        nestedTypes.Add(t);
        typeNames.Add(t.Name);
        propertiesNames.Add(p.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Its correct. Thanks for your time! i really appreciate. I accept this answer as the solution!